# Set NetworkX edge length

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is there a way to set the edge length in a networkx graph ? For example, I have the following code which sets the first edge length=10, second edge length=1, and yet they have the identical length in the actual graph:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge('A', 'B', length = 1)
>>> G.add_edge('B', 'C', length=10)
>>> nx.draw(G, pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'))
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to make one of the edges 1/10th the length of the other? I want it to look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`minlen`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:minlen).

```
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge('A', 'B', minlen = 1)
>>> G.add_edge('B', 'C', minlen = 10)
>>> nx.draw(G, pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'))
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have graphviz installed. Does the above work only with 'graphviz'  layout positioning? (It doesn't work with 'spring_layout' (for me).)